# Clarification about GitHub Actions workflow and how it's operating

Tags: github-actions, digital-ocean, cicd

I need clarification on how a GitHub Actions workflow is working. I followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-deploy-your-application-to-digital-ocean-using-github-actions-and-save-up-on-ci-cd-costs-74b7315facc2). I have a DigitalOcean (DO) account and have deployed project on it, further the repo I am working on is https://github.com/AbdullahDev0/Food-Order-Management-System. Now the project is running using PM2 on watch mode.

What I want is to push the code on main and on pushing the code on main, it starts the workflow, updates the code on DO instance, recreates the build and pm2 restarts (pm2 is set on watch mode) and I set the YAML after reading GitHub docs and going here to do this.
For below code, I know its taking pull of code and updating on instance:

```yaml
     steps:
      - name: Update FOMS Code
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.10
        with:
          host: ${{secrets.SSH_HOST}} # IP address of the server you wish to ssh into
          key: ${{secrets.SSH_KEY}} # Private or public key of the server
          username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USERNAME }} # User of the server you want to ssh into
          script: |
            cd Food-Order-Management-System
            git pull
            cd ~
            echo 'Deployment successful to digital ocean'
```

Now I am not 100% sure what the below code is doing, for what I understood, it should have delinked its path from GitHub, should setup Node if it isn't set up, installs the dependencies and build the project.

```yaml
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18.0.0
      - name: Install Dependencies and Build Nest App
        run: |
          pwd
          ls -la
          npm ci
          npm install --prefix ./Rabbit-MQ
          npm run build
```

However I am getting logs as below:

```
/home/runner/work/Food-Order-Management-System/Food-Order-Management-System
total 696
drwxr-xr-x 7 runner docker   4096 Apr 26 15:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 runner docker   4096 Apr 26 15:39 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker    665 Apr 26 15:39 .eslintrc.js
drwxr-xr-x 8 runner docker   4096 Apr 26 15:39 .git
drwxr-xr-x 3 runner docker   4096 Apr 26 15:39 .github
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker    416 Apr 26 15:39 .gitignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker     51 Apr 26 15:39 .prettierrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker   2645 Apr 26 15:39 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 4 runner docker   4096 Apr 26 15:39 Rabbit-MQ
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker    118 Apr 26 15:39 nest-cli.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker 650226 Apr 26 15:39 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker   3074 Apr 26 15:39 package.json
drwxr-xr-x 7 runner docker   4096 Apr 26 15:39 src
drwxr-xr-x 2 runner docker   4096 Apr 26 15:39 test
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker     97 Apr 26 15:39 tsconfig.build.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker    546 Apr 26 15:39 tsconfig.json

added 807 packages, and audited 808 packages in 38s

94 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

14 vulnerabilities (4 moderate, 8 high, 2 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.

added 734 packages, and audited 735 packages in 19s

90 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

7 vulnerabilities (1 moderate, 6 high)

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.

> foms@0.0.1 prebuild
> rm -rf dist


> foms@0.0.1 build
> nest build
```

And I don't have Docker set up on my instance, I don't have path like `/home/runner/work/Food-Order-Management-System/Food-Order-Management-System`, and I am not sure where all this code is going. So I need help in understanding what's happening here.

Comment: _"I don't have Docker set up on my instance"_ - it's not running on your instance, it's running on GitHub's machine: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners.

Comment: In the first snippet, you're SSHing into your DO droplet and fetching code there. In the second one, it's all running inside the GHA-hosted runner which is a different machine that's why you're seeing those different paths and directory contents. The general idea is to build and test your code on the GHA-hosted runner and then deploy it on your server.

Comment: See [GitHub Actions docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions) for more details on all these elements in your workflow.

Comment: jonrsharpe and Azeem thanks for clarification. I will go through the docs thoroughly, and I would appreciate a lot if you can guide me (through some authentic sources apart from GitHub docs) on what to study about CI/CD that will be quite helpful. (Yes, I can find it on Google, but there are multiple articles with different tastes that makes it difficult to keep the head straight, so guide from seniors will be quite helpful!)